# Keep Client connection alive

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, tcp

I am a beginner in python socket programming. My question is, I have a TCP server in listen mode at that time client will send data to the server. But when my TCP server is unavailable at that I want a client to go and check for connection every time (something like try exception method with while loop).

I have tried tricks but that didn't work out, it gives o/p like connection refused when my TCP server is unavailable. Below is my code help me with same.

```
# client.py  
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
host = socket.gethostname()                           

port = 2195

s.connect((host, 2195))


while 1: 

    try:
        print "Try loop"
        s.sendall("Welcome to Python\r\n")
        print "Try loop2"
        time.sleep(5)


    except:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
        s.connect((host, port))
s.close()
```

Comment: You describe a perfectly sensibe solution: catch the exception, then you should sleep for a bit, then retry the connect attempt. But you haven't tried to implement that, nor have you described your actual, detailed problem.

Comment: My question is client code should go and check for connection everytime, in my code, it will check for 5seconds as my time.sleep(5).

Comment: @MeetAdhia: you are not trying to connect. Instead you expect the connect to succeed and then try to send. Only, if the TCP server is not available the connect will already fail and this is what you get (connection refused) and fail to catch.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many solutions but below code works for me.

## client.py

```
import socket

import time

while True:

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
    host = socket.gethostname()                           

    port = 2195

    try:
        s.connect((host , port))
        s.sendall("Welcome to Python\r\n")

    except:
        print "Error"

    time.sleep(5)
    s.close()
```